# Are numeric_limits min/max constexpr?

Tags: c++, c++11, standards-compliance, constexpr

Does the C++11 standard specify that the `numeric_limits<T>::min` and `max` have to be constant-expression that can be used in templates or `static_assert`?

More generally, how to find the list of the functions that are constant-expression according to the standard?

Comment: The main motivation behind the new keyword `constexpr` was to make the stuff in numeric_limits constant expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed the standard (or my latest working draft) lists all members of `std::numeric_limits` in chapter **18.3.2.3 [numeric.limits]** as `constexpr` (it won't do any good to actually quote those definitions here), for the general templated version as well as all the builtin specializations (**18.3.2.7 [numeric.special]**). So yes, they are guaranteed to be constant expressions (for conforming implementations that also actually support `constexpr`, of course).

As to your second, more general, question I cannot help you that much except just refer you to the C++ standard itself, whose latest draft, which doesn't really differ from the actual standard, is available for free. Or you might look at the more convenient but less binding [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/Main_Page).

Comment: For those affected, Visual Studio 2013 CTP November 2013 does *not* have constexpr numeric_limits, at least not for min() and max().

Comment: @EmilyL. Well, it doesn't have `constexpr` at all, does it?

Comment: It does, partly... it's "not yet implemented" for member functions. http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-00-65-69/0638.Updated-Conformance-Map.png